# How to debug "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This error is driving me crazy. The function throws this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Could someone point out where is the error?

```
   function ok()
   {
       if (document.getElementById('titulo')='') {
           AbreSnackBar('You have to give this piece a title','red');
           exit();
       }

        var data=
           'titulo=' + document.getElementById('titulo').value +
           '&plantilla=' + document.getElementById('plantilla').value +
           '&pags=' + document.getElementById('pags').value +
           '&genero=' + document.getElementById('gen').value +
           '&comp_real=' + document.getElementById('comp_orig').value +
           '&ano=' + document.getElementById('ano').value +
           '&up_im1=' + document.getElementById('up_im1').value +
           '&up_im2=' + document.getElementById('up_im2').value +
           '&up_im3=' + document.getElementById('up_im3').value +
           '&up_ref=' + document.getElementById('up_ref').value +
           '&video=' + document.getElementById('link').value +
           '&descr=' + document.getElementById('descr').value +
           '&descr_ing=' + document.getElementById('descr_ing').value +
           '&minutos=' + document.getElementById('minutos').value +
           '&dificultad=' + document.getElementById('dif').value +
           '&up_PDF=' + document.getElementById('up_PDF').value + 
           '&up_RAR=' + document.getElementById('up_RAR').value +
           '&up_MUS=' + document.getElementById('up_MUS').value +
           '&up_SIB=' + document.getElementById('up_SIB').value +
           //'&tags=' + document.getElementById('tags').value +
           '&modo=' + document.getElementById('modo').value +
           '&id_concurso=' + document.getElementById('id_concurso').value +
           '&copias_min=' + document.getElementById('copias_min').value;

        AbreSnackBar('Wait...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",       url: "acc_sube_obra.php", data: data ,
            success: function (data) 
            {
                alert(data);
                switch (data.trim())
                {
                    case '0':
                        AbreSnackBar('An error ocurred','red');
                        break;
                    default: //id
                        AbreSnackBar('Done!','green');
                        window.location.href = 'http://www.aboutscores.com/obra_subida.php?id='+ data.trim();
                }
            } 
        }); 
   }
```

I've seen that the cause could be that I'm *trying to assign a new value to the result of a function*, but I don't see that's the case.

I didn't post the code of *AbreSnackBar* (OpenSnackBar) function because it works perfectly and it's irrelevant.

Comment: Here: `if(document.getElementById('titulo')='')`. This doesn’t even make sense. You can’t assign the return value of a function call to anything and even if you meant to compare the two values with `==`, this would never be true, because this function never returns an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById('titulo')='') {
                   right there ------^
```

Bit by the assignment operator, you probably meant `==` instead.

However, as Xufox points out, `null != ''`.

The statement should probably be:

```
if (document.getElementById('titulo') === null) {
```

or

```
if(document.getElementById('titulo').value == '')
```

Comment: This was probably meant to be `if(document.getElementById('titulo').value == '')`.

Comment: Thank you, @user866762. I forgot 1 `=`. I come from Visual Basic, sorry. Problem solved.